# python variable contents changed by function when no change is intended

Tags: python, scope

Here is a sample of code where a function is run repeatedly with new information for most of the input variables except one, good_ens.  The input variable good_ens that should never be changed, gets changed.  What is going on here?  This defies my understanding of scope.

```
def doFile(infileName, outfileName, goodens, timetype, flen):

    print('infilename = %s' % infileName)
    print('outfilename = %s' % outfileName)
    print('goodens at input are from %d to %d' % (goodens[0],goodens[1]))
    print('timetype is %s' % timetype)

    maxens = flen # fake file length
    print('%s time variable has %d ensembles' % (infileName,maxens))

    # TODO - goodens[1] has the file size from the previous file run when multiple files are processed!
    if goodens[1] < 0:
        goodens[1] = maxens

    print('goodens adjusted for input file length are from %d to %d' % (goodens[0],goodens[1]))

    nens = goodens[1]-goodens[0]
    print('creating new netCDF file %s with %d records (should match input file)' % (outfileName, nens))


# user settings
datapath = ""

datafiles = ['file0.nc',\
             'file1.nc',\
             'file2.nc',\
             'file3.nc']
# fake file lengths for this demonstration
datalengths = [357056, 357086, 357060, 199866]
outfileroot = 'outfile'
attFile = datapath + 'attfile.txt'
# this gets changed!  It should never be changed!
# ask for all ensembles in the file
good_ens = [0,-1]

# --------------  beyond here the user should not need to change things
for filenum in range(len(datafiles)):

    print('\n--------------\n')
    print('Input Parameters before function call')
    print(good_ens)
    inputFile = datapath + datafiles[filenum]
    print(inputFile)
    l = datalengths[filenum]
    print(l)
    outputFile = datapath + ('%s%03d.cdf' % (outfileroot,filenum))
    print(outputFile)

    print('Converting from %s to %s' % (inputFile,outputFile))
    # the variable good_ens gets changed by this calling function, and should not be
    doFile(inputFile, outputFile, good_ens, 'CF', l)
    # this works, but will not work for me in using this function
    #doNortekRawFile(inputFile, outputFile, [0,-1], 'CF', l)
```

Output for the first two iterations of the for loop is below.  Note good_ens gets changed from [0, -1] to the value of goodens that is inside the function.  Why?  Never mind the difference in variable names, they don't even share the same scope.

```
--------------

Input Parameters before function call
[0, -1]
file0.nc
357056
outfile000.cdf
Converting from file0.nc to outfile000.cdf
infilename = file0.nc
outfilename = outfile000.cdf
goodens at input are from 0 to -1
timetype is CF
file0.nc time variable has 357056 ensembles
goodens adjusted for input file length are from 0 to 357056
creating new netCDF file outfile000.cdf with 357056 records (should match input file)

--------------

Input Parameters before function call
[0, 357056]
file1.nc
357086
outfile001.cdf
Converting from file1.nc to outfile001.cdf
infilename = file1.nc
outfilename = outfile001.cdf
goodens at input are from 0 to 357056
timetype is CF
file1.nc time variable has 357086 ensembles
goodens adjusted for input file length are from 0 to 357056
creating new netCDF file outfile001.cdf with 357056 records (should match input file)

--------------
```

There is a similar question here:
[Python issue value of property changes when falling out of loop scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606819/python-issue-value-of-property-changes-when-falling-out-of-loop-scope)

However I do not want to embed the variable good_ens down in a for loop.  I want its value to be set by the user once at the head of a script, then used in the for loop.

Comment: Your variable type is a mutable list. You mutate the list in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `doFile` try this instead:

`doFile(inputFile, outputFile, list(good_ens), 'CF', l)`

I think of it this way: A list is a thing which points to the value of each element within the list. When you pass a list into a function, **the thing that does the pointing** gets copied, but **the values of the things pointed to** do not get copied.

doing `list(good_ens)` actually makes copies in memory of the elements of the list, and will keep the original values from getting changed. See below:

```
>>> def change_list(the_list):
...     the_list[0] = 77
...     return
...
>>> a=[0,1,2,3,4]
>>> change_list(a)
>>> a
[77, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
>>> a=[0,1,2,3,4]
>>> change_list(list(a))
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

EDIT: The reasoning for this is that, as the other answers have indicated, list is a mutable data type in python. Mutable data types can be changed, whereas immutable data types cannot be changed but rather return new objects when attempting to update.

Comment: OK, as a C programmer, I understand.  Following this logic, this means that all values are in all scopes in python because it's always pointers being sent into functions?  In C, if a pointer were sent, one would expressly declare it as a pointer.

Comment: I vote this best answer.  For python newbies out there, note that it is not sufficient to say gens = goodens in the code, that just perpetuates passing the pointer, undesirable behavior here.  Instead explicitly passing the contents with gens = goodens[:] is necessary to fix the problem

Comment: It does not apply to all data types, only the mutable ones. Most common data types like int and string are immutable. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In python, lists are mutable.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> def fun(d):
...  d.append(55)
...
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> fun(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 55]
>>> fun(a[:])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 55]
>>> fun(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 55, 55]
```

If you want them to be immutable consider using a tuple.

Comment: Yes, good_ens needs to be mutable for future plans with this work.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover the idea that [lists are mutable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists). Below is a possible refactoring that gets around this issue in what I think is a sensible way.

```
def doFile(infileName, outfileName, goodens, timetype, flen):
    # ...
    min_ens, max_ens = goodens

    if max_ens < 0:
        max_ens = flen

    nens = max_ens - min_ens
    # ...
```

This way, you can still call the function as you have been, your variables within the function are named more aptly, and you never mutate the provided list object.